# autopep8 error --indent-size

Tags: atom-editor, autopep8

Recently installed atom-beautify package in Atom. I'm using Linux as OS. i've installed the missing autopep8 python package and i'm still getting this unexpected error.

> autopep8: error: no such option: --indent-size

Anyone knows why? Below is the full stacktrace!

> Usage: autopep8 [options] [filename [filename ...]] Use filename '-'
>   for stdin.
>
> autopep8: error: no such option: --indent-size
>
> ```
> Usage: autopep8 [options] [filename [filename ...]]
> Use filename '-'  for stdin.
> autopep8: error: no such option: --indent-size
> Hide Stack Trace
> Error: Usage: autopep8 [options] [filename [filename ...]]
> Use filename '-'  for stdin.
> autopep8: error: no such option: --indent-size
>     at /home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:287:27
>     at tryCatcher (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
>     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:561:18)
>     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
>     at Promise._settlePromises (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:685:18)
>     at Async._drainQueue (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
>     at Async._drainQueues (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
>     at Async.drainQueues (/home/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:392:9)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

apt-get remove it then install through pip:
pip install autopep8